# React Native Elements , Card Style Overlay Issue

Tags: react-native, expo

## react-native-element

I'm using https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/card/

React native elements, for some reason when the image is set into the card. It's dark, the original image isn't like this.

I tried it on different pages, all the same "dark image" result.

[image]

```
import { Card, Button, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
    <Card
              title='Title'
              image={{uri: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Singapore,+Bukit+Batok&zoom=17&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&format=jpg&visual_refresh=false&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:1%7CSingapore,+Bukit+Batok'}}>
              <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
              <Button
                icon={{name:'my-location'}}
                backgroundColor='#03A9F4'
                buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
                title='Button' />
            </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/pull/637

It's a bug, will be fixed the next release